# Asignar icono a una aplicacion por codigo Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, mvvm

Estoy intentando asignar el icono a mi aplicacion mediante codigo, se que se puede hacer mediante las propiedades del proyecto, pero debido a que deseo que mi aplicacion sea configurable, tambien deseo que el icono lo sea.

Consegui esta opcion:

```
public static void SetConsoleIcon()
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            SetWindowIcon(Properties.Resources.iconosistema);
        }
    }
    public enum WinMessages : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An application sends the WM_SETICON message to associate a new large or small icon with a window. 
        /// The system displays the large icon in the ALT+TAB dialog box, and the small icon in the window caption. 
        /// </summary>
        SETICON = 0x0080,
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static void SetWindowIcon(System.Drawing.Icon icon)
    {
        IntPtr mwHandle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        IntPtr result01 = SendMessage(mwHandle, (int)WinMessages.SETICON, 0, icon.Handle);
        IntPtr result02 = SendMessage(mwHandle, (int)WinMessages.SETICON, 1, icon.Handle);
    }// SetWindowIcon()
```

Funciona, pero solo se muestra por 0.01 segundos y luego cambia al predeterminado. Esta funcion lo pongo en el MainWindow que se llama al iniciar el proyecto.

El tema es que, no se donde deberia asignar el icono para que quede con el que se le asigno y no cambie, ese es mi problema, espero su ayuda por favor.

Comment: Quieres modificar el icono de una ventana de WPF, verdad?

Comment: De toda la aplicacion WPF

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario recurrir al API de Windows para cambiar el icono, debería llegar con cambiar la propiedad `this.Icon` del formulario.

Un ejemplo de uso:

`this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icono.ico");`

o en tu caso, creo que con esto llegaría:

`this.Icon = Properties.Resources.iconosistema`

Para WPF exactamente igual. Lo único que puede ser diferente es que tienes que cambiarlo para MainWindow y la propiedad es un bitmap que es diferente tipo a lo que tienes guardado en resources.

`this.Icon = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(Properties.Resources.iconosistema.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());`

Paso un pequeño ejemplo para que puedas hacer corta y pega: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43179733/192389

Comment: Puede que dea pena traducirlo, pero dado que la única respuesta que das que sea para WPF es un enlace y un enlace solo no es una respuesta válida... Por favor, añade la información del enlace en tu respuesta, o esto es más bien un comentario que una respuesta y acabará eliminada o con votos negativos!

Comment: @Benito-B solucionado. Puedes quitar el negativo.